# How do I find out which DVD drive an AutoPlay event is for?

Tags: .net, com, autoplay

I have an autoplay event handler registered with COM for DVD movies.

I am using C#, and followed this guide from CodeProject:http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/AutoplayDemo.aspx

When a DVD movie is inserted I see my handler in the list and it does fire (I added Debugger.Break() inside the code so I could debug it)

In my object, I implement the IDropTarget interface, and my Drop event gets called.

However for DVD movies I cannot interrogate the IDataObject passed in. A call to IDataObject.QueryGetData with the "Autoplay Enumerated IDList Array" format returns the int value 1 instead of S_OK (0). This does not seem to be one of the defined output values for the QueryGetData call and has me totally at a loss.

The autoplay event log (%SystemRoot%\Autoplay.log) says: ~0x000006E0~[0312]DVD Movie -> No Content Autoplay!

Does this mean that I can't get told which DVD drive started the event? Granted most systems will only have one, but I would still like to interrogate the correct device to get the movie info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went and checked how VLC does it. Instead of using a COM Object as the codeproject example does, they map their exe directly to the registry action.

Then they use the %1 substitution parameter in their action command line, which makes Windows automatically substitute in the drive that the autoplay event is for.

This is a much simpler solution for DVD playback (granted the codeproject example is to catch all files examined by the content type detection, so it is not exactly for the same purpose as I needed)